# lldb Windows errors with clang 10

Tags: lldb, clang++, llvm-clang

I have clang 10.0.0 for Windows installed from [here](https://releases.llvm.org/download.html)

I also used the community VS installer to install 3 components that I understood were needed for clang 10:

- C++ 2019 Redistributable Update
- MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools (v14.26)
- Windows 10 SDK (10.0.18362.0)

clang itself works ok -  I can compile, link with `-fuse-ld=lld`, run some code with concepts, `std::span`, looks good.

When I run `lldb.exe`, I get:

`..python36.dll was not found..`

If I put `python36.dll` on the path, I then get:

`The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)..`

I'm learning C++, wanted to start using a debugger but I'm getting stuck here.

Do I need to install the entire Python 3.6 for this to work? (I have 3.8 already installed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed the 64bit version of `python36.dll`, got it from [wikidll](https://wikidll.com/python-software-foundation/python36-dll)

Comment: Don't download dlls from random places, they are as dangerous as exes. If you have Python 3.6 installed, just search your PC for "python36.dll", copy it, search again for the folder containing "lldb.exe" and paste it there.